# ajax vs button(action) submission for configuration/option settings

Tags: buttons, ajax, interactive-ui, submit

I read this post ([ajax checkboxes vs submit button](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19577/ajax-checkboxes-vs-submit-button)) on a similar topic and I am at an impasse.

I've noticed a move towards active changes for configuration and settings in applications for all sorts of environments (web, mobile, desktop). I'm of the opinion that the analog effect of checking a box with a pen on a piece of paper has a direct digital equivalent to checking a box and having that commit. Meaning, on paper, I can check a box and I can erase. In a UI, I can check a box (which makes the change) and I can uncheck (which undoes the initial change). Some batch operations can be defined as "Check/Uncheck All".

Having UI's with several groups of binary controls is the area of conflict between me and my co-worker, who is a DBA. His main point is that a submit button should be used to reduce the number of hits to the server. While I concur with items that are not binary, such as updating account information (email, password, etc), I find that configurations/options (on/off) should not follow the "account" update paradigm.

It would make sense for an option that has significant impact to have a confirm message before execution. I also understand that latency needs to be taken into consideration in a decision like this, but I feel that most if not all of this can be handled with proper UI logic.

What are the latest schools of thought on this topic (specifically for the web)?

this question is NOT the same as the question related "marked as duplicate". I am EXPLICITLY asking about latest schools of thought from the "World of UX" thinkers, not one post with one reply by one individual with one specific question about a specific use case.

More to the point, "What is the direction of UX development with regards to nixing the action/command button in lieu of ajax "on-demand" committing of changes. Followed by: "what are the schools of thought about handling edge cases?"

**EDIT**

To go even further:
Is this a trend?
Is this even on the minds of UX developers?
Is there no thought on active actions in the web context? 
Is *anyone* discussing topics like this? 
In seeing how "[Config] ON/OFF" sliders are widely used in mobile and desktop apps, has there been *any* intelligent discussion on viability for this same paradigm for the web?
Finally, what other respected UX sites/blogs exist where I might find out if there is any thought/discussion on this topic?

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE! Please check out the [faq](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) and [about](http://ux.stackexchange.com/about) pages to get a good start!

Comment: If you're after a high level view from the "World of UX" then your question may be slightly too broad.

Comment: This is still the same question as the linked dupe, as far as I can tell. You're also asking several extra questions too, which aren't really answerable ("are there any respected blogs/sites". "Is this a trend..." "latest schools of thought from the "World of UX" thinkers"- these aren't specific practical answerable questions which this site is designed for). I think that if you want more / better answers on the linked question then adding a bounty on the linked question is preferable so that answers aren't split across multiple very similar posts.

Comment: I understand the frustration with this being closed, but it's not just the people below who believe it's a duplicate - this question has been flagged by other users too stating the same thing (although such flags aren't visible to non-moderators / <10K users).

Comment: I disagree. The linked question poses a specific scenario in which he requests answers for specific when/why "opinions". I am not asking for such opinions. I'm asking for information regarding current directions in UX with regards to handling configuration/options settings. If I were to ask you all what you have experienced in regard to what the direction of user experiences is taking, I might get a slew of answers which could illustrate a trend depending upon responses. The additional questions were an attempt to try to draw this out.